# Properties in C# as a protection against whom?

Tags: c#, properties

```
public class X
{
private int number;
public void SetNumber(int nmbr)
{ if nmbr != 0 this.number = nmbr; }
public void GetNumber()
{ return this.number; }
}
```

I'm reading introductory texts on C#, and every now and then I come across explanations about something, that is related to security issues, usually in terms of who can access and modify fields. For example, properties are defined as mediators between internal fields and external direct access. What confuses me is how this can be the issue if I as a coder don't implement anything in the software's interface that directly modifies certain field? Imagine this field 'number' is from some basic math application. If I don't design interface in a way that has direct access to certain field, how is this an issue? Is this something related to potential vulnerability, i.e. preventing app to be hacked? Or are properties protection against coders themselves, who can forget what they intended to do in complex projects?

Comment: Properties have absolutely nothing to do with "security".  Please ensure you do not walk away believing that it does.  Furthermore, I think when you say "security" you are referring to `public`, `protected`, etc.  None of even _that_ has anything to do with security.  Accessor keywords like that are only designed to prevent developers from shooting themselves in the foot.  It would still never prevent a curious or mischievous engineer from accessing any class member that is "protected" via keywords such as `private`.

Comment: _are properties protection against coders themselves, who can forget what they intended to do in complex projects?_ Yes, that comes close.

Comment: Adding to what Kirk said: I once (purely out of interest) completely bypassed a library's licensing restrictions by replacing the backing methods for its properties (which belonged to a `private` class that I accessed using reflection (i.e. I did this at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

My simple understanding of properties is that they are more a convenience utility that *converts* data between internal fields (i.e private not visible/accessible from outside, and also not intended to be read/set by a user) and the *public API* of a class (visible/accessible to/by the user, **intended to be used by the user**).

Consider for example:

```
private long millis;

public TimeSpan SomeDuration
{
    get
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millis);
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == default)
            throw new ArgumentException("blah");

        millis = value.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

That's a trivial example, but here the user can *conveniently* read a TimeSpan-datum, while the actual value is stored in a *"less beautiful"* long-field.

So my point here is that properties are **tailored to the user**, while their underlying data is not - even if they are referring to the same information.

Further, this also somehow **contributes to security**, because in the above example, the private field `millis` is somehow *protected* against *improper use* - either an intended or accidental one.

Comment: `TimeSpan` is a struct...

Comment: I meant: `if (value == null)` value, which is a TimeSpan (struct), cannot be null. Rather use `if (value == default)`